# C++, Nested Classes, Cross Referencing

Tags: c++, data-structures, adjacency-list, cross-reference

Last week, I was working on a homework, that asked us to implement a directed graph data structure. I decided to implement my graph as an adjacency list. below in the picture, you can see the idea I had.[image: İmage 1]
To implement this structure, I created two nested structures. CityListNode, and RouteListNode. (In the homework, we were building a software for an airline company) In this implementation, vertexes are implemented as a linked list, and each edge between vertexes is also a linked list. When I tried to use a pointer in each edge to point back to the vertex the edge was connecting, I started facing errors due to cross-referencing. Below you can see a simplified version of the class declaration. Is there a way to fix this error? Should I always stay away from cross-referencing? How would you implement two different nodes having pointers to each other?
Thanks in advance :)

```html
class AirlineGraph{
private:
    class routeListNode{
        public:
            cityListNode* destination;
            routeListNode *next;   
    };
    class cityListNode{
        public:
            string cityName;
            int cityNumber;
            cityListNode *next;
            routeListNode *root;   
    };
    int numCity , numRoute;
    cityListNode* cityListRoot;
    ...
    ...
    ...
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a forward declaration, e.g.:

`class AirlineGraph::cityListNode;`

...however, you can't do that for nested classes in C++.  Only classes at global or namespace scope.  It's a deficiency in the language.

Your only solutions here are to un-nest one of the classes so it can be forward declared, or use a base/derived hierarchy and forward declare the base.

I'd probably just un-nest the classes.  That seems like a fine solution to me.  Slap it all in a namespace if you like.

Answer (score 1):

With std, you might simplify the code to

```
class AirlineGraph{
private:
    class City{
    public:
        // forbid copy, as we use reference to city
        // and want to be sure to avoid possible relocation
        City(const City&) = delete;
        City operator=(const City&) = delete;

        std::string cityName;
        int cityNumber;
        std::vector<City*> dests; // observer pointer
    };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<City>> cities; // use pointer,
                                               // instead of by value, so pointer are still valid
                                               // after a resize.
};
```